# actionscript 3 - use textfield text in for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, trace

I have 5 dynamic textFields on stage. They have instance names of `txtField_1`, `txtField_2` through `txt_Field_5`.

if I wanted to trace the data inside it, I would write:

```
trace(txtField_1.text);
trace(txtField_2.text);
.
.
.
trace(txtField_5.text);
```

what if I wanted to do this in a for loop?

I'm looking for something like:

```
for (i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++)
{
   trace(txtField_[i].text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `this[ "variableName" ]` syntax.

```
var fields:uint = 5;

for ( var i:uint = 1; i <= fields; i++ ) {
    trace( this[ "txtField_" + i ].text ); //you may need to cast as a TextField to avoid compiler errors
}
```

`this["variableName"]` is the same as accessing `this.variableName`, but it allows you to use a variable within the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that if your TextFields are in an Array.

```
var _textFields:Array = new Array();
_textFields.push(new TextField());
_textFields.push(new TextField());
_textFields.push(new TextField());
_textFields.push(new TextField());
_textFields.push(new TextField());
_textFields[0].text = "text field 1 text";
_textFields[1].text = "text field 2 text";
_textFields[2].text = "text field 3 text";
_textFields[3].text = "text field 4 text";
_textFields[4].text = "text field 5 text";
```

Then:

```
for (var loop:uint=0;loop<_textFields.length;loop++) {
    trace(_textFields[loop].text);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the textFields are on the stage, not in an array. Do you suggest anything else?

Comment: @MiladGhattavi You could... Put them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
private function getTextFields():void{
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < stage.numChildren; i++){
        if(stage.getChildAt(i) is TextField){
            // Whatever needs to be done with the text. e.g. putting it to an array ;);
            trace(TextField(stage.getChildAt(i)).text;
        }
    }
}
```